# How to check if a web server is reachable in Linux?

Tags: monitoring, monit

I want to poll every few minutes if an external web server is reachable from the Linux server.

Assume the server is 10.20.30.40.

I'm following this guide.

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/hosts-network-availability

The server is not pingable although it is reachable.

Meaning ping will not succeed.

Sadly netcat isn't installed.

But I can telnet the server at port 443

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would do this with an endpoint (specific URL) on the server.  That way you test both the network access and server availablility (IE not crashed) in the same request.

A simple `curl` request would be sifficient to check.  For example:

```bash
curl -f -LI http://example.com/foo/bar
```

Will return a 0 exit code (success) if example.com responds with a 2xx success [HTTP status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).  You can build this into a shell script with a simple if statement:

```bash
if curl -f -LI http://example.com/foo/bar ; then
  echo success
else
  echo failed
fi
```

---

To chose an endpoint, you may want to look at the specific webserver you are running.  Some offer a "healthcheck" endpoint for this specific purpose.  If not, then often the homepage (`/`) is a good choice.

Comment: curl fails timed out

Comment: @barnyard9 that would usually point to the server being down, crashed, or otherwise inaccessable.  Are you sure it is up and accessable from the box you are trying to connect from?

Comment: yes it's accessible via telnet.

Comment: again, as Philip says, if curl times out, then *something* accepting a TCP connection to port 443 (what you test with telnet, I understand) doesn't tell us anything. Something's going wrong there!

Comment: I'd rather delete this qestion as this generates unnecessary confusions.

Answer (score 2):

> The server is not pingable although it is reachable.

So, first of all: fix your damn ICMP! There's no reason why you'd suppress pings, and doing so makes various things unnecessarily hard. Path MTU discovery becomes harder, network problems harder to detect, and it comes for free. I've had the experience that exactly those networks blocking ICMP packets, making pinging impossible, are those who then end up having TTL limits undetectable on the outside, surprising MTU problems, including "impossible" TCP connections that can be established, but then fail to work.

Nobody likes a host who can't tell you when something is bad about your connectivity to it. Fix your ICMP.

> But I can telnet the server at port 443

as Philip Couling illustrates above, for a full HTTPS request, use `curl`.

If you are content when just the TLS connection establishment works, `openssl s_client` can do that for you:

```bash
echo | openssl s_client yourhost:443 || printf 'FAAAAIL!\n'
```

Generally, if you want to set up a monitoring system for services, go with someone that someone else already wrote. If you need things to observe multiple servers, notify you via mail or message, setting up a Grafana (incl Prometheus and sensors) on a server of yours might be worth your time.